# Can you extend an enum?

Tags: swift, enums

I use enums to store string values like this:

```
    enum Animals: String {
        case descCat = "I has attitude"
        case descDog = "how can I help"
        case descGator = "I will eat you"
        var s: String {
            get {
                return self.rawValue as String
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I access them like this:

```
print("Dogs be like:" + Animals.descDog.s)
```

My question is can I extend enums like any other struct or object so I don't have to add the `var s: String {}` property to each enum?

Comment: `self.rawValue` is already of type `String` in your enum. Why are you casting it?

Comment: What do you mean by "add the `var s: String{}` property to each enum?" Do you mean "every kind of enum?" You can't do that with structs or objects. Do you mean something else?

Comment: Maybe I don't need the as String cast in the s{} property. Seems like I did at some point but don't seem to be able to recreate now.

Comment: I add the s {} property regularly to enums because it is shorter and cleaner than rawValue. I don't need to add it to every kind of enum just ones of type String.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You want to add a property to all enums whose raw value is a string? This sounds like a case for constrained protocol extensions!

```
extension RawRepresentable where RawValue == String {
    var description: String {
        return rawValue
    }
}
```

This works because all enums with a raw value automatically conform to the `RawRepresentable` protocol, and said protocol has an associated type `RawValue` that tells you which type the raw value is.

Now your `Animals` enum will automatically inherit it:

```
print(Animals.descCat.description) // -> "I has attitude"
```

Notice that string enums are themselves already `CustomStringConvertible`, so they already have a `description` property (that returns the name of the enum case), and yours doesn't override it:

```
print(Animals.descCat) // -> "descCat"
```

If you want your `description` to override the default, just add a declaration of `CustomStringConvertible` conformance to your enum:

```
private enum Animals: String, CustomStringConvertible { /*...*/ }
print(Animals.descCat) // -> "I has attitude"
```

---

You can also extend this idea to cover other raw value types. For example:

```
extension RawRepresentable where RawValue: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return rawValue.description
    }
}
```

Now, you can get automatic descriptions for enums whose raw value is `Int` or even a custom type (so long as that type has a `description` of its own).

Comment: better than my answer, got my vote sir! Did not think about that. However even if the rawValue isn't a `String` you can still convert a lot of types to `String`

Comment: Good point. I edited my answer to extended the extensions further. (Yo dawg...)

Comment: Thanks for this awesome answer. Regarding overriding CustomStringConvertable: print(Animals.descCat) works but assigning to a string variable or passing as an arguement fails e.g.: let fooString: String = Animals.descCat gives a conversion error. My solution was to add the s {} property

Comment: Right -- `description` is for automatic "use it like a string contextually" cases, like `print`, string interpolation, and the debugger/playground. (Also, I started writing my answer about `description` because your question had that in it before you edited it. :) If you want to extend `RawRepresentable` to add a new property, you can still make use of the type constraints and/or call-through to `rawValue.description` for that.

Comment: The first solution worked but the version added to the answer yielded error: Type 'RawValue' (aka 'String') does not conform to protocol 'CustomStringConvertible'

Comment: @MindSpiker: Sorry I wasn't clear on that -- `String` does not itself conform to `CustomStringConvertible`, so you have to use the original solution for `String` enums and the other for otherwise-string-representable enums.

Comment: @rickster When compiling using top initial solution I get error : type 'RawValue' constrained to non-protocol type 'String' to test i started a new project and tried the same solution and was able to compile no problem??? So the solution works but not for my project. Any ideas?

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you, rickster