# Swift: extension of enum UIModalTransitionStyle

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift-extensions, uimodalpresentationstyle

How can I add a new `case` in enum [UIModalTransitionStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodaltransitionstyle)?

Is that feasible using swift [extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html)?

Swift document about [extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) says that: Extensions add new functionality to an existing class, structure, **enumeration**, or protocol type.

Does it mean, I can create an extension for `enum`?

[UIModalTransitionStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodaltransitionstyle) has following four cases:

- case [coverVertical](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodaltransitionstyle/1621455-coververtical)
- case [flipHorizontal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodaltransitionstyle/1621444-fliphorizontal)
- case [crossDissolve](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodaltransitionstyle/1621370-crossdissolve)
- case [partialCurl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodaltransitionstyle/1621497-partialcurl)

> I want to add one more case **push** in it. How can I do that?

I found only this on SO, that doesn't help (or I'm unable to understand, how to use that solution for my problem resolution) :

- [Can you extend an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444932/can-you-extend-an-enum)

Comment: Extensible enums are discussed here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0192-non-exhaustive-enums.md.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is **no way** to directly add more cases to an enum. The documentation refers to adding for e.g. computed properties and functions to an existing enumeration.

Your best bet would be extending UIModalTransitionStyle with more cases with the method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40823730/3151675).