# Create a DRY function for multiple enums (enum subclassing?)

Tags: swift, enums, dry

I have multiple enums which will all share an identical function. Is there a way to write this function once and have it present in all specified enums? Here is an example:

```
enum CustomerTypes: Int, CaseIterable {
    case NewCustomer = 0
    case ExistingCustomer
    case Myself

    private var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .NewCustomer : return StandardStrings.NewDrive.NewCustomer.string
        case .ExistingCustomer : return StandardStrings.NewDrive.ExistingCustomer.string
        case .Myself : return StandardStrings.NewDrive.Myself.string
        }
    }

    static var titles: [String] {
        get {
            var toReturn: [String] = []
            for value in allCases {
                toReturn.append(value.title)
            }

            return toReturn
        }
    }
}

enum EnquiryTypes: Int, CaseIterable {
    case Phone = 0
    case FaceToFace

    private var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .Phone : return StandardStrings.Misc.Phone.string
        case .FaceToFace : return StandardStrings.Misc.FaceToFace.string
        }
    }

    static var titles: [String] {
        get {
            var toReturn: [String] = []
            for value in allCases {
                toReturn.append(value.title)
            }

            return toReturn
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see here, both enums share identical "titles" variables. Is there a way I can possibly create an enum/class in which they can inherit this function from?

**Here are some things I have tried:**
[Can you extend an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444932/can-you-extend-an-enum)
I considered this, but I don't want to extend ALL functions that have Int rawValues

I considered creating a protocol, then creating a function which took the protocol like this, but I still would need to implement the _allCases on every enum (as you can't inherit from CaseIterable):

```
protocol RBEnum {
    var title: String { get }
    var _allCases: [RBEnum] { get }
}
```

So any ideas how I can avoid violating DRY principles on these enums?

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578694/defining-a-swift-protocol-for-arbitrary-int-based-enums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A protocol is the right approach. Not sure why do you think protocols cannot inherit from each other, but they can, so you can make your protocol inherit from `CaseIterable`.

You can also significantly simplify `titled` by using `map` instead of a `for..in` loop and getting rid of the useless `get` specifier. A getter is the default accessor for a computed property, you don't need to wrap your closure in `get { ... }` unless you are creating both a getter and a setter.

```
protocol Titled: CaseIterable {
    var title: String { get }
    static var titles: [String] { get }
}

extension Titled {
    static var titles: [String] { allCases.map(\.title) }
}
```

Then you just need to keep the `title` property on your enums and make them conform to `Titled` and due to the default implementation you get `titles` for free.

Unrelated to your question, but enum cases should be lowerCamelCase like all variables.

```
enum CustomerTypes: Int, Titled {
    case newCustomer = 0
    case existingCustomer
    case myself

    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .newCustomer : return "new"
        case .existingCustomer : return "existing"
        case .myself : return "my"
        }
    }
}

enum EnquiryTypes: Int, Titled {
    case phone = 0
    case faceToFace

    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .phone : return "phone"
        case .faceToFace : return "face"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `allCases.map(\.title)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom protocol, for instance:

```
protocol HasTitle: CaseIterable {
    var title: String { get }
}

extension HasTitle {
    static var titles : [String] { allCases.map { $0.title } }
}
```

and then make your enums conform to your new protocol:

```
enum CustomerTypes: Int, HasTitle {
    case NewCustomer = 0
    case ExistingCustomer
    case Myself

    private var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .NewCustomer : return StandardStrings.NewDrive.NewCustomer.string
        case .ExistingCustomer : return StandardStrings.NewDrive.ExistingCustomer.string
        case .Myself : return StandardStrings.NewDrive.Myself.string
        }
    }
}
```